# Confusion in MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have a machine that had a running version of MySQL 5.6 used in an apache tomcat Java app. I needed to install WampServer 3.1 for a PHP project which comes with a MySQL 5.7. 
I read that I have to change the port of wampserver MySQL to keep everything working as they were. I changed it to 3308 as suggested by wamp. 
However, now I can't use mysql through cmd. I reverted back to port 3306, I can now use mysql. 
The confusion however is that typing in the cmd:

```
mysql --version
```

returns

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

but using this command from MySQL:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

returns

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried uninstalling wampserver, but then I couldn't user mysql again. So I re-installed.

I don't want to use MySQL 5.7 with the apache tomcat Java app as it might cause problems with the projects if MySQL version migration is not done properly and it is something that I can't afford now.

If possible, can I keep both wampserver and MySQL 5.6? If not, how can I revert the situation?

Edit: when typing in cmd:

```
where mysql
```

it returns

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe
```

but the version is as mentioned above 5.7

Comment: Certainly you can operate both, but you really should use the newer one. The differences are small, changes hardly neccessary, except maybe in really complex projects. If you want to keep both then yes, you need to operatre them on different ports, since MS-Windows does not support file based unix-Sockets. You can certainly interact with a mysql server on any port, _if you specify the port number on CLI_...

Comment: Ah, thanks! Will check how to do so